# What do the arguments mean in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, max

Can you describe what this statement in `matlab` means? I know it will find the `max`. But, what do the arguments mean?

```
max(r,[],1);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation first?

Answer (score 3):

First two arguments could be matrices or array which have to be compared and the output is the matrix containing larger elements. The third argument points a dimension in multidimensional arrays in which finding of max element will be provided. This argument is enable only if the second matrix is empty. If the second array is not empty and, at the same time, third argument is presented, MATLAB shows an error message. Thus, we have three options in using:

```
1) max(A)
2) max(A,B)
3) max(A,[],dim)
```

If we use all three arguments where both matrices are non empty, we will get this error message:

> Error using max MAX with two matrices to compare and a working dimension is not supported.

If B is a constant the function compares all elements of the matrix A with this scalar. Thus, the expression `max(A,2)` does not mean finding maximum along the second dimesion but it means compare each element with 2 and return the largest element. For example:

```
>> A=[1 1 1;2 2 2;3 3 3];max(A,2)

ans =

     2     2     2
     2     2     2
     3     3     3

>> A=[1 1 1;2 2 2;3 3 3];max(A,[],2)

ans =

     1
     2
     3
```

Comment: When using `[]` as a second argument, what does that mean?

Comment: This means that we are able to use third argument which is the variable dim.

Comment: Instead of doing max(A,A,2); empty matrix is better.

Comment: No, example above is not going to work. Here is the output: Error using max
MAX with two matrices to compare and a working dimension is not supported.